# Cache HTML using request-promise and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, caching, request

I'm looking for a simple way to cache HTML that I pull using the [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) library.

The way I've done this in the past is specify a `time-to-live` say one day. Then I take the parameters passed into request and I hash them. Then whenever a request is made I save the HTML contents on the file-system in a specific folder and name the file the name of the `hash` and the `unix` timestamp. Then when a request is made for the using the same parameters I check if the cache is still relevant via timestamp and pull it or make a new request.

Is there any library that can help with this that can wrap around request? Does request have a method of doing this natively?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a key value store that supports time to live, say [Redis](http://redis.io/commands/expire) or [Memcached](http://docs.libmemcached.org/memcached_set.html)? Seems like you could save a ton of file system manipulation and the keys could just be your hash.

Comment: @YetAnotherUserName are you suggesting to plop the entire HTML page into redis and set the key to the hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the recco in the comments and used Redis. Note this only works for get requests.

```
/* cached requests */
async function cacheRequest(options){
  let stringOptions = JSON.stringify(options)
  let optionsHashed = crypto.createHash('md5').update(stringOptions).digest('hex')
  let get = await client.getAsync(optionsHashed)
  if (get) return get
  let HTML = await request.get(options)
  await client.setAsync(optionsHashed, HTML)
  return HTML
}
```